# A batch file to run from windows 11

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

I want to make a very simple bat file to run from windows 11 home screen. When I click it, it should shows files in the directory in command screen.

Tried:

```
CMD dir
```

```
CMD /k dir
```

Didn't work.

Expect the command screen to show the result of Dir

Comment: "Didn't work" doesn't tell us a lot. How is it not working? What do you see? What are you expecting to see? Are you seeing any error messages? We need much more information before we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a batch file (`.bat` or `.cmd` extension).

1. Open a text editor.
2. The following should be inside of it -

```
@echo off
dir
pause
```

This script will open a command prompt window, execute the `dir` command to list the files in the directory where the batch file resides, and then display the results. The `pause` command ensures the window remains open until a key is pressed to close it.

`@echo off` -  prevents the command prompt from displaying the commands as they're executed. The `@` symbol before `echo off` suppresses the echoing of the command itself in the output.